# How can a page tell browsers that an AMP HTML version exists?

Tags: amp-html

I understand I will have two pages, the AMP one and the regular one. The AMP one has a canonical link to the regular one, but how does the regular one specify that there is a AMP version available?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [AMP document discovery documentation](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-html-format.md#amp-document-discovery) specifies that you need to add this tag in the `<head>`:

```
<link rel="amphtml" href="...">
```

As an example, if you take a look at a page from a publisher that already supports AMP, such as http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-europe-34471849, you can see this tag in the `<head>`:

```
<link rel="amphtml" href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/amp/34471849">
```

Comment: If you go to the non amp page via a mobile device it renders the non amp page. Is there a way to force the mobile device to render the amp version of the page?

Comment: Why it don't use the content negotiating part of HTTP?

Comment: There is a discussion about some slight tweaks to how this is done within the github bug pages: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/498

Comment: I wrote a quick and dirty chrome extension to allow quick switching from amp to regular - it's intended for developers and includes an option to force the #development=1 validation tag.  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/amplifier/ennckgigejppolagdoadgaaodkhopjnb

Comment: How we set <title> inside the head of an amp pages, which depends upon URL path/route?